# zend_barcode in MVC

Tags: php, image, zend-framework, png, barcode

i just want an Action to print a barcode image, but i can´t get this working in MVC, i just do the following:

```
public function barcodeAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    Zend_Barcode::render($_GET['barcodeType'], 'image', $_GET, $_GET);
}
```

but when I call

```
/barcode?barcodeType=code39&text=ZEND-FRAMEWORK
```

I just obtain:
"The image couldn't be displayed because it has errors" (or something like that, browser-dependant).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely getting an error that you can't see due to the `Content-Type` header that's sent by `Zend_Barcode`.  Make sure you have `log_errors` turned on and a valid/writeable destination for the log configured.  This way you can check the error log for anything that you normally would have read through your browser.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors

Comment: thanks, but Zend_Barcode sets the Content-type correctly to image/png as you can see in http://online.cooprc.com.ar/facturas/codigo/factura/0001-01249361/para/PF, but this seems to happen only in the MVC, because calling this single line: "Zend_Barcode::render($_GET['barcodeType'], 'image', $_GET, $_GET);
" in a file in the public folder works like a charm... as you can see in http://online.cooprc.com.ar/barcode.php?text=90000101249361.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you verify your error output settings? I mentioned that the `Content-Type was` set by `Zend_Barcode`, which means the browser is going to expect image data. If PHP sends a string error message to the browser, the browser will consider it to be a corrupt image (which will cause the message you mentioned in your question), since it's expecting an image (based on the `Content-Type`) and not string data.

You can correct this by telling PHP not to display errors but to log them to a file instead. This way you can figure out what's going on. (See links above in my original answer)

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with your code, I call this url: http://localhost/index/barcode?barcodeType=code39&text=ZEND  in my browser (your code is in the IndexController) and I receive the correct image.

If I put `<img src="http://localhost/index/barcode?barcodeType=code39&text=ZEND" />` in a view, I have also the image.

Mickael

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be outdated now but when I had the same problem I just added

```
ob_clean();
```

in my controller so now my action looks like this

```
public function generateBarcodeAction() {
    ob_clean();
    $number = $this->params()->fromRoute('number');
    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => $number);
    $rendererOptions = array('imageType'=>'png');
    Barcode::render(
            'ean13', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
    );
}
```

and it's working like a charm